# main screen opens two times when I login using firebase phone authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Login.java

```
package com.example.simpleaccounting;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
import com.google.zxing.pdf417.encoder.PDF417;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText countryCodeEdit, phoneNumberEdit;
    private Button mSendOTPBtn;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    TextView processText;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallBacks;
    private Boolean authFlag = false;
    //permission constants
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    //image pick constants
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE = 102;
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE = 103;
    //arrays of permissions
    private String[] cameraPermissions; //camera and storage
    private String[] storagePermissions; // only storage
    //variables (will contain data to save)
    private Uri imageUri;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        mSendOTPBtn = findViewById(R.id.send_codebtn);
        processText = findViewById(R.id.text_process);
        countryCodeEdit = findViewById(R.id.input_country_code);
        phoneNumberEdit = findViewById(R.id.input_phone);

        //init permission arrays
        cameraPermissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        requestCameraPermission();

        //set by default text for country code
        countryCodeEdit.setText("91");
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mSendOTPBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //initialize progress dialog
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
                //show progress dialog
                progressDialog.show();

                //set Content View
                progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);
                //set transparent background
                progressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(
                        android.R.color.transparent
                );
                String country_code = countryCodeEdit.getText().toString();
                String phone = phoneNumberEdit.getText().toString();
                String phoneNumber = "+" + country_code + "" + phone;
                if (!country_code.isEmpty() || !phone.isEmpty()) {
                    PhoneAuthOptions options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
                            .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .setActivity(Login.this)
                            .setCallbacks(mCallBacks)
                            .build();
                    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
                } else {
                    processText.setText("Please Enter Country Code and Phone Number");
                    processText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    processText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        mCallBacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                signIn(phoneAuthCredential);
            }
            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                processText.setText(e.getMessage());
                processText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                processText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                processText.setText("OTP has been Sent");
                processText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent otpIntent = new Intent(Login.this, otp.class);
                        otpIntent.putExtra("auth", s);
                        startActivity(otpIntent);
                    }
                }, 10000);
            }
        };
    }
    private void requestCameraPermission() {
        //request the camera permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, cameraPermissions, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        //result of permssion allowed/denied

        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    //if allowed returns true otherwise false
                    boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean storageAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    Toast.makeText(this, cameraAccepted + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }

            }
            break;


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //dismiss progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            sendToMain();
        }
    }

    private void sendToMain() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private void signIn(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    sendToMain();
                } else {
                    processText.setText(task.getException().getMessage());
                    processText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    processText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my login activity.
When i write the otp manually , then i don't have this issue, main activity opens only one time but when it auto reads the otp and directly sends me to main activity from login (skipping otp screen) then main activity opens two times.
OTP.java

```
package com.example.simpleaccounting;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;

public class otp extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mVerifyCodeBtn;
    private EditText otpEdit;
    private String OTP;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp);
        mVerifyCodeBtn = findViewById(R.id.verifycode_btn);
        otpEdit = findViewById(R.id.verify_code_edit);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        OTP = getIntent().getStringExtra("auth");
        mVerifyCodeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String verification_code = otpEdit.getText().toString();
                if(!verification_code.isEmpty()){
                    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(OTP,verification_code);
                    signIn(credential);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(otp.this,"Please Enter OTP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void signIn(PhoneAuthCredential credential){
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    sendToMain();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(otp.this,"Verification Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser!=null){
            sendToMain();
        }
    }
    private void sendToMain(){
        startActivity(new Intent(otp.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

And this is my otp screen activity code.
after login my main activity opens but within 5 seconds my main activity opens again. Can anyone help me out with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: This happens also in javascript